# Extracting three words before the first occurrence of a particular word

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have been trying to extract three words before the first occurrence of a particular word.
For eg,
Input: **Kerala High Court Jurisdiction.**
Known Word: **Jurisdiction.**
Output: **Kerala High Court**

---

I have tried the following regular exception, but it didn't work.

```
m = re.search("((?:\S+\s+){3,}\JURISDICTION\b\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){3,})",contents)
print(m)
```

Comment: Do you really want or need to use regular expressions for this? I would split the string into words, get the `.index` of the word in the list, and slice accordingly.

Comment: Alternatively, you could split the string at the "particular word" (with regex splitting, for instance) so that you can either post-process the prefixed string or simply use as is.

Comment: Like `if "Jurisdiction" in s: print(s.split("Jurisdiction")[0])` with `s` as the input string.

Comment: Is it really always three? Or is this just like the famous XY problem instance of someone asking about the last three characters of a filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is multiple ways to do so:

```
# Method 1
# Split the sentence into words and get the index of "Jurisdiction"
data = "Word Kerala High Court Jurisdiction"
words = data.split()
new_data = words[words.index('Jurisdiction')-3:words.index('Jurisdiction')]
print(new_data)  # ['Kerala', 'High', 'Court']

# Method 2
# Split the sentence to "Jurisdiction" and the text before into word
data = "Word Kerala High Court Jurisdiction"
new_data = data.split('Jurisdiction')[0].split()[-3:]
print(new_data)  # ['Kerala', 'High', 'Court']


# Method 3
# Using regex
import re

data = "Word Kerala High Court Jurisdiction"
new_data = re.search(r"(\w+\W+){3}(?=Jurisdiction)", data)
print(new_data.group())  # Kerala High Court
```

---

- `(){3}`: capturing group, repeated 3 times.

  - `\w+`: matches a word character between one and unlimited times.
  - `\W+`: matches any character different than a word character between one and unlimited times.
- `(?=)`: Positive lookahead.
- `Jurisdiction`: Matches `Jurisdiction`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` for this, the pattern could look like: `^([\w ]+)Jurisdiction`

```py
import re
s = """Kerala High Court Jurisdiction."""
print(re.findall(r"^([\w ]+)Jurisdiction", s)[0].strip().split())
# ['Kerala', 'High', 'Court']
```

Explanation:

```py
re.findall(r"^([\w ]+)Jurisdiction", s)
```

gives you `['Kerala High Court ']`

```py
[0].strip().split()
```

Takes the first element of above list, strips the whitespaces and then splits it at whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```py
matches = re.findall(r'(?:\b\w+\s+){3}(?=Jurisdiction)', contents, flags = re.I)
for match in matched:
    print(match)
```

The expression looks for three words before the word 'Jurisdiction'.

`re.I` is to make it case insensitive.

You're supposed to use a forward look ahead `(?=...)` to check if the match precedes a pattern. You can remove `?=` if you want to include the word `Jurisdiction` in your matches.

Answer (score 0):

About the pattern that you tried:

- Using `{3,}` repeats 3 or more times instead of exactly 3
- You don't have to escape the `\J`
- The pattern ends with `\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){3,}` which means that the repeating pattern should be present after matching *JURISDICTION*
- You use a capture group around the whole pattern, but instead you can capture only the part that you want, and match what should be present before (or also after it)

To extract 3 words before the first occurrence, you can use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), and use a capture group instead of a lookahead.

```
(\S+(?:\s+\S+){2})\s+JURISDICTION\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
  - `(?:\s+\S+){2}` Repeat 2 times matching 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ non whitspace chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s+JURISDICTION\b` Match 1+ whitespace chars, JURISDICTION followed by a word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0TNI2Z/1).

For example, using `re.I` for a case insensitive match:

```
import re

pattern = r"(\S+(?:\s+\S+){2})\s+JURISDICTION\b"
s = "Kerala High Court Jurisdiction"

m = re.search(pattern, s, re.I)

if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
Kerala High Court
```